# vue.js component template rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In the following code I expected everything to be rendered inline, but they are not. Why isn't the component rendered inline when it is a span?

```
    <div id='app'>
        <span v-for="ville in nomVilles">
           <span>{{ville}}  </span>
        </span>

       <liste-villes :villes ="nomVilles"></liste-villes>  
    </div>



    Vue.component('liste-villes',{
      template: '<span >\
                   <span v-for="ville in villes">\
                      <p>{{ville}} </p>\
                   </span>\
               </span>  ',
      props: ['villes']
    });

    var vm = new Vue ({
      el:'#app',
      data: {
        nomVilles:['Vancouver','Montreal']
      }
    })
```

Comment: You're rendering a paragraph tag inside each span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **span** element is an **inline** element, while the **p** tag is a **block** element.

You are trying to render a paragraph element inside a span tag, so it still takes up the entire block level, forcing the next span to not be inline.